# How do I create a bubble sort in C that can take in any type of array?

Tags: c, pointers, bubble-sort

We are trying to create a bubble sort that can take in an `int`, float, or c-string array. We already wrote the swap function that allows us to do this, but now we cannot figure out how to get it to work with the bubble sort.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void swapG(void* a, void* b, int elemSize)
{
    void* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * elemSize);
    assert(temp != NULL);
    memcpy(temp, a, elemSize);
    memcpy(a, b, elemSize);
    memcpy(b, temp, elemSize);

    free(temp);
}

void bubbleSort(void* arr[], int n, int elemSize)
{
    int i, j;
    bool swapped;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        swapped = false;
        for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            if (&arr[j] > &arr[j + 1]) {
                swapG(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1], elemSize);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        if (swapped == false)
            break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf(&arr[i]);
}

int main()
{
    int* arr[] = { 0,1,4,6,9,10,13,7 };
    bubbleSort(arr, 8, sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to pass a pointer to a comparison function that will match the passed array type. Look at how `qsort()` works. I'd suggest to do the same for the `swap` function BTW.

Comment: `if (compG(arr, j, j+1, elemSize) > 0)` ... where `compG()` returns `-1` (or some other negative value), `0`, or `1` (or another positive value) according to the relationship between elements `j` and `j+1`

Comment: Another way is adding `#define DEFINE_BUBBLESORT(type) void bubblesort_##type(type *base, ...) { ... }` to the `.h` file, and the adding `DEFINE_BUBBLESORT(int)` to the .c file, and calling it as `bubblesort_int(...)`.

Comment: ...or you could combine the compare and swap functions.

Comment: Somewhat OT: the malloc/free in the swapG function is extremely inefficient. Also swapping elements will be inefficient if the element size is large, in that case it might be better to sort pointers to the elements. OK, bubble sort itself is already inefficient...

Comment: It's possible to swap each byte, without a memory allocation.

Comment: If I am reading it correctly, the swap function is actually swapping the elements in memory, not just in the array. That's a very bad idea. I don't think you need the `elemSize` parameter anywhere, array elements are pointers and you just need to swap pointers.

Comment: `void swap(void **a, void **b) { void *t = *a; *a = *b; *b = t; }`

Comment: @vgru It can still be used for swapping pointers by passing the size of the pointer. Depending that considered to be the element.

Comment: You need to specify how you want the data types to be compared and then swap based on the sorting rules you specify. Again, you should distinguish between sorting elements and sorting collection, swap the sorting elements in that collection.

Comment: `int* arr[] = { 0,1,4,6,9,10,13,7 };` Your compiler should be yelling at this line. Fix it. Then fix every other line that the compiler complains about. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function pointer parameter for your sorting function like this:

```
int (*comparison_function)(void *, void *)
```

This is the function that’ll compare the two elements of you array. You can call it with this:

```
(*comparison_function)(argument_1, argument_2);
```

Now you just need to define different functions for each type, and when you call your sorting function pass the comparison function name like this:

```
((*)(void *, void *)) comparrison_function
```

Comment: Since OP doesn't see this from the start, perhaps you should add some practical examples too?

Comment: Better use `const void*` for the parameters. Also, if you need to cast `comparison_function`, you are probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this approach is that the underlying type is not abstracted. This is not a matter of just adding `elemSize`. Off-topic: camelCase is so so java ;) why not just `size` and `size_t`?

```
        void bubbleSort(int* arr[], size_t size)
```

And the data could be `Array`, encapsulating the size and whatever metadata one could find useful, like in

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    int*   arr;
}  Array;
```

Anyway, I see this question as an interesting one and I will left below a way of doing this, as it is very common the need to sort or just proccess arrays of different things.

I will write as I code so this will be a long post, ending with a complete program that sorts over the 3 types and shows how to encapsulate behavior in `C` making sort of an *object* for the array we sort on.

### First: we need `bubble_sort`

First thing needed is a working bubble sort implementation. Let us try this common one:

```
int bubble_sort(int vector[], int N)
{
    int step = 0;
    int el   = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for (step = 0; step < N - 1; step = step + 1)
    {
        int changed = 0;  // no change
        for (el = 0; el < (N - 1 - step); el = el + 1)
        {
            if (vector[el] > vector[el + 1])
            {
                temp          = vector[el];
                vector[el]     = vector[el + 1];
                vector[el + 1] = temp;
                changed    = 1;
            }  // if
        }      // for
        if (changed == 0)
            return step + 1;  
    }                         
    return step + 1; // number of swaps
};
```

This one returns the number of swaps made in order to sort the array. Not important here.

We need to test it. Is it possible NOT to print the array before and after? No. We would like that: the array is sorted.

```
int show_int(int arr[], int N, const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("%d elements\n", N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 1) printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
};
```

So this 8-line thing above could help: it shows the array and admits an optional handy message, so no need to write dozens of calls to `printf` during testing

#### a first test, with `int`

```
int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7};
    show_int(arr, 8, "before sort: ");
    bubble_sort(arr, 8);
    show_int(arr, 8, "after sort: ");
    return 0;
}
```

#### and the output

```
before sort: 8 elements
2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7

after sort: 8 elements
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

And it is great since we did almost nothing and have a function and a test.

#### back to `bubble_sort`

If we want to sort `int`, `float` or `char*` it is the same algorithm. Looking at the code we see that we need to know

- how to swap 2 itens:

```
            temp          = vector[el];
            vector[el]     = vector[el + 1];
            vector[el + 1] = temp;
            changed    = 1;
```

- how to compare 2 items:

```
            if (vector[el] > vector[el + 1])
```

And this is all we need.

#### extracting the operations

Would it be hard to get these out of `bubble_sort()`?

Consider:

```
int cmp_int(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b;
};

void swap_int(int* a, int* b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a       = *b;
    *b       = temp;
    return;
};
```

Well, not so hard. Back to `bubble_sort`:

```
int bubble_sort(int vector[], int N)
{
    int step = 0;
    int el   = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for (step = 0; step < N - 1; step = step + 1)
    {
        int changed = 0;  // no change
        for (el = 0; el < (N - 1 - step); el = el + 1)
            if (cmp_int(vector[el],vector[el + 1]))
            {
                swap_int(vector+el,vector+el+1);
                changed = 1;
        }
        if (changed == 0) return step + 1;
    }
    return step + 1;  // number of swaps
}
```

And it works as before. **Good.**

### making `swap` and `compare` generic

Since we want to sort different things, like patient records, books in the library, tickets, `int`, strings, all the usual students' stuff, let us change cmp_int and swap to use just `void*`, with no types...

#### `cmp_int`

If we got two `void*` pointing to the original `int`s...

```
int cmp_int(void* one, void* other)
{
    int a = *(int*)one;
    int b = *(int*)other;
    return a > b;
};
```

#### `swap_int`

If `swap_int` arguments were also `void*` we could use

```
void swap_int(void* one, void* other)
{
    int* a    = one;
    int* b    = other;
    int  temp = *a;
    *a        = *b;
    *b        = temp;
    return;
};
```

Sure, no need for so many lines and variables, but there are 6 lines anyway.

#### bubble_sort using the new `swap` and `compare`

```
int bubble_sort(int vector[], int N)
{
    int step = 0;
    int el   = 0;
    for (step = 0; step < N - 1; step = step + 1)
    {
        int changed = 0;  // no change
        for (el = 0; el < (N - 1 - step); el = el + 1)
            if (cmp_int(
                    (void*)(vector + el),
                    (void*)(vector + el + 1)))
            {
                swap_int((void*)(vector + el),(void*)(vector + el + 1));
                changed = 1;
            }
        if (changed == 0) return step + 1;
    }
    return step + 1;  // number of swaps
}
```

And it works as before. **Still good.**

But now `bubble_sort` does not know the type of things in the array it is sorting on. only `swap_int` and `cmp_int` are important. Let us change names:

```
int bubble_sort(int vector[], int N)
{
    int step = 0;
    int el   = 0;
    for (step = 0; step < N - 1; step = step + 1)
    {
        int changed = 0;  // no change
        for (el = 0; el < (N - 1 - step); el = el + 1)
            if (cmp(
                    (void*)(vector + el),
                    (void*)(vector + el + 1)))
            {
                swap((void*)(vector + el),(void*)(vector + el + 1));
                changed = 1;
            }
        if (changed == 0) return step + 1;
    }
    return step + 1;  // number of swaps
}
```

But the vector is still declared as `int[]` and this is not generic. We begin to change this now...

We have only `swap` and `cmp`. There are two functions with similar signatures:

```
    int  cmp(void*, void*);
    void swap(void*, void*);
```

So what if we pass this 2 functions as arguments to `bubble_sort`?

`C` was designed for this type of things.

Let us see:

#### `bubble_sort()` gets 2 new arguments

```
int  bubble_sort(int[], int N,
     int (*)(void*, void*),
    void (*)(void*, void*)
    );
```

Now we can pass custom `cmp` and `swap` to `bubble_sort`, in our way to be able to sort anything.

#### changing `main` to provide the new arguments

It is just the matter of providing the functions to be used:

```
int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7};
    show_int(arr, 8, "before sort: ");
    bubble_sort(arr, 8, cmp_int, swap_int);
    show_int(arr, 8, "after sort: ");
    return 0;
}
```

#### The output

```
before sort: 8 elements
2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7

after sort: 8 elements
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Is the same, for sure. **Still good.**

### Could we already sort an array of `double`?

Sure, it is the same thing. But we still have `bubble_sort` first argument as `int[]`. **Not good.**

We are still not there. Let us change `bubble_sort()` to

```
int bubble_sort(
    char* array, size_t el_size, size_t N, int (*cmp)(void*, void*),
    void (*swap)(void*, void*));
```

So we can operate on the array as an address and offset, as all arrays are after all.

`C` was designed to operate on this kind of stuff: system buffers, inter-process messages, message queues and such.

`array` is the base address, `el_size` is used to iterate on the `array` memory block. The rest is what we have: the *bubble sort*.

#### `bubble_sort()` generic, in 20 lines

This version does not know what is in the array:

```
int bubble_sort(
    char* arr, size_t el_size, size_t N,
    int (*cmp)(void*, void*), void (*swap)(void*, void*))
{
    int    step = 0;
    size_t el   = 0;
    for (step = 0; step < N - 1; step += 1)
    {
        char* offset  = arr;
        int   changed = 0;  // no change
        for (el = 0; el < (N - 1 - step);
             el += 1, offset += el_size)
            if (cmp(offset, offset + el_size))
            {
                swap(offset, offset + el_size);
                changed = 1;
            }
        if (changed == 0) return step + 1;
    }
    return step + 1;  // number of swaps
}
```

It is the same code as before, but `swap` and `cmp` are arguments, `arr` is the array, and `el_size` is the size of each element.

It is an *object*  in some sense: the user needs to pass the data and the methods to operate on data.

In reality it is just a matter of copy and paste from one type to another.

#### implementing `swap` and `compare` for doubles and strings

```
int   cmp_int(void*, void*);
void  swap_int(void*, void*);

int   cmp_double(void*, void*);
void  swap_double(void*, void*);

int   cmp_string(void*, void*);
void  swap_string(void*, void*);
```

just like that. Sure it is the same for `Tickets`, `Patient`, whatever data we need to operate on. This is **OOP**, as ever.

#### implementation for these functions

```
int cmp_int(void* one, void* other)
{
    int a = *(int*)one;
    int b = *(int*)other;
    return a > b;
};

void swap_int(void* one, void* other)
{
    int* a    = one;
    int* b    = other;
    int  temp = *a;
    *a        = *b;
    *b        = temp;
    return;
}

// functions for double

int cmp_double(void* one, void* other)
{
    double a = *(double*)one;
    double b = *(double*)other;
    return a > b;
}

void swap_double(void* one, void* other)
{
    double* a    = one;
    double* b    = other;
    double  temp = *a;
    *a           = *b;
    *b           = temp;
    return;
}

// functions for strings

int cmp_string(void* one, void* other)
{
    char** a   = one;
    char** b   = other;
    int   res = strcmp(*a, *b);
    return res > 0;
}

void swap_string(void* one, void* other)
{
    if (one == NULL) return;
    if (other == NULL) return;
    char** a = one;
    char** b = other;
    char* temp = *a;  // save now
    *a         = *b;
    *b         = temp;
    return;
};
```

And this is all we need. Need to sort a new type? Just write `swap` and `compare`.

#### Abstracting `show` method: printing any type

This is the *java*  `toString`, the `C++` `<<` override method...

We have in the example

```
int show(int arr[], int N, const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("%d elements\n", N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 1) printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
};
```

And it works. But used `%d` to print an element, and iterates over an `int[]` array. **Not good.**

If the user could tell us how to show one element, then we could just use it in `show()`. The power of *objects*...

#### `show` an int: 7 lines

Consider a function like

```
char* show_int(void* p)
{
    char* str = malloc(30);
    if (str == NULL) return NULL;
    int res = snprintf(str, 30, "%d", *(int*)p);
    return str;
}
```

It works for `int`: just returns a string that represents its value. But we can change it to use `double`:

#### copy and paste to `show` a double: 7 lines

```
char* show_double(void* p)
{
    char* str = malloc(50);
    if (str == NULL) return NULL;
    int res = snprintf(str, 30, "%f", *((double*)p));
    return str;
}
```

#### copy and paste to `show` a string: 10 lines

```
char* show_string(void* p)
{
    char** a = p;
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;
    size_t len = 1 + strlen((char*)*a);
    char*  str = malloc(len);
    if (str == NULL) return NULL;
    strcpy(str, (char*)*a);  // copy to output
    return str;
}
```

#### change `show` to work for any type: 19 lines

```
int show(
    char* arr, size_t elem_size, size_t N,
    char* (*show_one)(void*), const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("%llu elements\n", N);
    char* pStr   = NULL;
    char* offset = arr;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        pStr = show_one(offset);
        printf("%s ", pStr);
        free(pStr);
        offset += elem_size;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
};
```

**This is the same approach used in `bubble_sort`: seeing the data as an object, the user needs to just provide code for the 3 functions and we can sort on anything. And we can also show any data on screen, since `show` gets an user-provided sort of *virtual* function to show an element.**

### a complete example: `main.c`

```
int main(void)
{
    // int
    int arr[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7};
    show(
        (char*)arr, sizeof(int), 8, show_int,
        "before sort: ");
    bubble_sort(
        (char*)arr, sizeof(int), 8, cmp_int, swap_int);
    show(
        (char*)arr, sizeof(int), 8, show_int,
        "after sort: ");

    // double
    double f_arr[] = {1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8,
                      1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7};
    show(
        (char*)f_arr, sizeof(double), 8, show_double,
        "before sort: ");
    bubble_sort(
        (char*)f_arr, sizeof(double), 8, cmp_double,
        swap_double);
    show(
        (char*)f_arr, sizeof(double), 8, show_double,
        "after sort: ");

    // string
    char* str_arr[] = {"Bravo", "Delta", "Fox", "Hotel",
                       "Alpha", "Charlie", "Eco", "Golf"};
    show(
        (char*)str_arr, sizeof(char*), 8, show_string,
        "before sort: ");
    bubble_sort(
        (char*)str_arr, sizeof(double), 8, cmp_string,
        swap_string);
    show(
        (char*)str_arr, sizeof(double), 8, show_string,
        "after sort: ");
    return 0;
}
```

This code, using copy and paste, declares an sorts 3 arrays of `int`, `double` and `char*`. And is almost the same code we stated with.

### output for this program: sorting all 3 types

#### and `printing` with the same function

```
before sort: 8 elements
2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7

after sort: 8 elements
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

before sort: 8 elements
1.200000 1.400000 1.600000 1.800000 1.100000 1.300000 1.500000 1.700000

after sort: 8 elements
1.100000 1.200000 1.300000 1.400000 1.500000 1.600000 1.700000 1.800000

before sort: 8 elements
Bravo Delta Fox Hotel Alpha Charlie Eco Golf

after sort: 8 elements
Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta Eco Fox Golf Hotel
```

### The complete `C` code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int bubble_sort(
    char*, size_t el_size, size_t N, int (*)(void*, void*),
    void (*)(void*, void*));

int   cmp_int(void*, void*);
void  swap_int(void*, void*);

int   cmp_double(void*, void*);
void  swap_double(void*, void*);

int   cmp_string(void*, void*);
void  swap_string(void*, void*);

char* show_int(void*);
char* show_double(void*);
char* show_string(void*);

int show(
    char*, size_t, size_t, char* (*)(void*), const char*);

int main(void)
{
    // int
    int arr[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7};
    show(
        (char*)arr, sizeof(int), 8, show_int,
        "before sort: ");
    bubble_sort(
        (char*)arr, sizeof(int), 8, cmp_int, swap_int);
    show(
        (char*)arr, sizeof(int), 8, show_int,
        "after sort: ");

    // double
    double f_arr[] = {1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8,
                      1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7};
    show(
        (char*)f_arr, sizeof(double), 8, show_double,
        "before sort: ");
    bubble_sort(
        (char*)f_arr, sizeof(double), 8, cmp_double,
        swap_double);
    show(
        (char*)f_arr, sizeof(double), 8, show_double,
        "after sort: ");

    // string
    char* str_arr[] = {"Bravo", "Delta", "Fox", "Hotel",
                       "Alpha", "Charlie", "Eco", "Golf"};
    show(
        (char*)str_arr, sizeof(char*), 8, show_string,
        "before sort: ");
    bubble_sort(
        (char*)str_arr, sizeof(double), 8, cmp_string,
        swap_string);
    show(
        (char*)str_arr, sizeof(double), 8, show_string,
        "after sort: ");
    return 0;
}

int bubble_sort(
    char* arr, size_t el_size, size_t N,
    int (*cmp)(void*, void*), void (*swap)(void*, void*))
{
    int    step = 0;
    size_t el   = 0;
    for (step = 0; step < N - 1; step += 1)
    {
        char* offset  = arr;
        int   changed = 0;  // no change
        for (el = 0; el < (N - 1 - step);
             el += 1, offset += el_size)
            if (cmp(offset, offset + el_size))
            {
                swap(offset, offset + el_size);
                changed = 1;
            }
        if (changed == 0) return step + 1;
    }
    return step + 1;  // number of swaps
}

// functions for int

int cmp_int(void* one, void* other)
{
    int a = *(int*)one;
    int b = *(int*)other;
    return a > b;
};

void swap_int(void* one, void* other)
{
    int* a    = one;
    int* b    = other;
    int  temp = *a;
    *a        = *b;
    *b        = temp;
    return;
}

// functions for double

int cmp_double(void* one, void* other)
{
    double a = *(double*)one;
    double b = *(double*)other;
    return a > b;
}

void swap_double(void* one, void* other)
{
    double* a    = one;
    double* b    = other;
    double  temp = *a;
    *a           = *b;
    *b           = temp;
    return;
}


// functions for strings

int cmp_string(void* one, void* other)
{
    char** a   = one;
    char** b   = other;
    int   res = strcmp(*a, *b);
    return res > 0;
}

void swap_string(void* one, void* other)
{
    if (one == NULL) return;
    if (other == NULL) return;
    char** a = one;
    char** b = other;
    char* temp = *a;  // save now
    *a         = *b;
    *b         = temp;
    return;
};

char* show_int(void* p)
{
    char* str = malloc(30);
    if (str == NULL) return NULL;
    int res = snprintf(str, 30, "%d", *(int*)p);
    return str;
}

char* show_double(void* p)
{
    char* str = malloc(50);
    if (str == NULL) return NULL;
    int res = snprintf(str, 30, "%f", *((double*)p));
    return str;
}

char* show_string(void* p)
{
    char** a = p;
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;
    size_t len = 1 + strlen((char*)*a);
    char*  str = malloc(len);
    if (str == NULL) return NULL;
    strcpy(str, (char*)*a);  // copy to output
    return str;
}

// show anything
int show(
    char* arr, size_t elem_size, size_t N,
    char* (*show_one)(void*), const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("%llu elements\n", N);
    char* pStr   = NULL;
    char* offset = arr;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        pStr = show_one(offset);
        printf("%s ", pStr);
        free(pStr);
        offset += elem_size;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: You are incredible, I cannot properly explain how grateful I am for the time you took to show me this in this amount of detail. May I ask how you and anyone else just know how to do this? I am a senior Computer Science student and while you guys impress me more than anything, I can't help but feel so ignorant when I see what you guys can do. Is there a point in a professional career where all this clicks? Thank you again for all of this!

Comment: I am glad this post could help you. I found your question very very good as a way to show a way of using some principles, valid from `COBOL` to `python` to `C++` to `ASM`. Principles in general associated with object oriented programming, and here used in an iterative way. Encapsulation, Abstraction and single responsibility principle in particular. I just set up 2 screens, one with the markdown file, other with an IDE and took your post and a version of `sort` I wrote from some forum. And copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

#### Do not ignore compiler warnings

You appear to be ignoring warnings from your compiler.

First, the print statement

```
        printf(&arr[i]);
```

is invalid because the first parameter is not a format string.

And second, the initialized declaration:

```
    int* arr[] = { 0,1,4,6,9,10,13,7 };
```

is invalid because your initializer list contains `int`s, but you are trying to initialize an array of `int*`.

#### Your function only accepts an array of `void*`

In your question, you ask:

> We are trying to create a bubble sort that can take in an `int`, `float`, or c-string array.

Your bubble sort function has the following prototype:

`void bubbleSort(void* arr[], int n, int elemSize);`

Even if your intention was to pass in an array of pointers, your function fails to do what you desire. While a pointer to some type `T` can be converted to `void *` and vice versa, there is no such valid conversion between an array of `T*` to array of `void*`. The types are not compatible.

<sub>The nitty gritty of it is that a `void*` (and `char*`) is allowed to be wider than a `T*`.</sub>

#### Utilize existing solutions as templates to follow

There is a prototype you can emulate to do what you want. That is the standard C function `qsort`

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
           int (*compare)(const void *, const void *));
```

We notice two differences between this prototype and one generated for your bubble sort. First, the array pointer is presented as a single `void*` instead of as an array. Second, the comparison function to be used is passed in as another parameter.

The first difference is what allows the function to take any kind of array. In C, an object of type array of `T` used in an expression (with a few exceptions) will decay to have type pointer to `T` instead, with the value of the address of its first array member. This pointer value is then naturally converted to `void*` as allowed by standard C.

The second difference allows you to pass in a different comparison function to accommodate different kinds of arrays. So, an array of `float` will want to use a different comparison function than an array of C-string.

So, your bubble sort function could become more like `qsort`

```
void bubbleSort(void *arr, int n, int elemSize,
                int (*Compare)(const void *, const void *))
```

#### How to use the comparison function

There are many resources on how to properly use `qsort`. But, in a nutshell, the trickiest part is understanding how to write a correct comparison function. The only trick, though, is that the arguments to the comparison function are pointers to elements of the array passed to `qsort`. The comparison function is to return a negative value if the first argument is less than the second argument, 0 if they are equal, and otherwise a positive value.

So if the sort function is passed an array of `int`s:

```
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    qsort(arr, 3, sizeof(int), cmp_int);
```

Then, the comparison function could look like:

```
int cmp_int (const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *aa = a;
    const int *bb = b;
    return (*aa < *bb) ? -1 : (*aa > *bb);
}
```

If the sort function is passed an array of pointers, then you will need to remember that each argument to the comparison function will be a pointer to a pointer. Such is the case when sorting C strings.

```
    const char *arr[] = { "world", "hello", "this" };
    qsort(arr, 3, sizeof(const char *), cmp_string);
```

So the comparison function implementation could look like this:

```
int cmp_string (const void *a, const void *b) {
    const char * const *aa = a;
    const char * const *bb = b;
    return strcmp(*aa, *bb);
}
```

#### Treating a `void*` as an array of elements

To treat the `arr` argument as an array, you could use a `char*` pointer to point to the location of the *i*<sup>_th</sup> element with an offset calculation.

```
    char * const arr2 = arr;
    ...
    void *p = &arr2[i * elemSize];
```

If you compiler supports the VLA extension, you could use that to make indexing a little more natural.

```
    char (* const arr2)[elemSize] = arr;
    ...
    void *p = &arr2[i];
```

#### Improving your generic swapping

You implemented a generic swap, but it is a bit expensive. In any sort algorithm, the swap operation should be as efficient as possible. However, you have added the expense of a call to `malloc` and `free` to every swap.

One way to deal with the issue is to only make one allocation for you swap temporary at the beginning of the sort, and release it when the sort is completed.

```
void bubbleSort(void *arr, int n, int elemSize,
                int (*Compare)(const void *, const void *)) {

    void *temp = malloc(elemSize);
    assert(temp != NULL);

    //...

    free(temp);
}
```

And now, you can modify your swap function to accept the temporary variable, instead of allocating one for yourself.

```
static inline void swapG(void* a, void* b, int elemSize, void *temp) {
    memcpy(temp, a, elemSize);
    memcpy(a, b, elemSize);
    memcpy(b, temp, elemSize);
}
```

To further optimize your allocation, you can create a buffer of fixed size to use for swapping, and only allocate if the element size is too large to fit.

```
void bubbleSort(void *arr, int n, int elemSize,
                int (*Compare)(const void *, const void *)) {

    char tempbuf[256];
    void *temp = tempbuf;

    if (elemSize > sizeof(tempbuf)) {
        temp = malloc(elemSize);
        assert(temp != NULL);
    }

    //...

    if (temp != tempbuf)
        free(temp);
}
```

#### We don't talk about bubble sort

The bubble sort algorithm itself is not really something you should spend a lot of time learning, so I will not discuss its implementation details in this answer.

#### How about the *selection sort*?

A more efficient sort algorithm that places the largest element at the end as bubble sort does is the *selection sort*. Selection sort works by identifying the largest element in the sub-array of interest, and places it into the last array position. The inductive step is to reduce the array size by one, and the stopping condition is when the array has fewer than 2 elements remaining.

> Algorithm for Array of N elements
>
> - let E = N
> - while E > 1
>
>   - find I such that Array[I] >= Array[x] for all x in [0..E)
>   - swap Array[I] and Array[E-1]
>   - let E = E - 1

With this algorithm, you will still have the invariant that the last part of the array is sorted while you shrink the array. While the function is now misnamed, the algorithm itself is not as silly.

```
void selectionSort(void *arr, int n, int elemSize,
                   int (*Compare)(const void *, const void *)) {

    char tempbuf[256];
    void *temp = tempbuf;

    if (elemSize > sizeof(tempbuf)) {
        temp = malloc(elemSize);
        assert(temp != NULL);
    }

    char (* const Array)[elemSize] = arr;

    int E = n;
    while (E > 1) {
        int I = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < E; ++i) {
            if (Compare(&Array[i], &Array[I]) > 0) I = i;
        }
        swapG(&Array[I], &Array[E-1], elemSize, temp);
        --E;
    }

    if (temp != tempbuf)
        free(temp);
}

// Not really the bubble sort
void bubbleSort(void *arr, int n, int elemSize,
                int (*Compare)(const void *, const void *)) {
    selectionSort(arr, n, elemSize, Compare);
}
```

#### How about the *insertion sort*?

The *insertion sort* is generally considered the most efficient sort for small arrays of unknown size. It works by inserting the next unsorted element into its correct relative position of an already sorted sub-array.

A consequence of this algorithm is that the temporary is not used for swapping, but to hold the value of the element of interest as its correct position is located. Once located, the elements are shifted up to make room for the value of interest. Array element movement of small arrays is considered efficient because it can be accomplished entirely in cache, and machines typically hard code optimized functions to perform the action.

> Algorithm for Array of N elements
>
> - let S = 1
> - while S < N
>
>   - let temp = Array[S]
>   - alias Array[-1] = temp
>   - find largest I in [-1, S) such that Array[S] >= Array[x] for x in [-1, I]
>   - move Array[I+1 .. S-1] to Array[I+2 .. S]
>   - let Array[I+1] = temp
>   - let S = S + 1

There are other ways to describe the algorithm, but the above is fairly straightforward to code:

```
void insertionSort(void *arr, int n, int elemSize,
                   int (*Compare)(const void *, const void *)) {

    char tempbuf[256];
    void *temp = tempbuf;

    if (elemSize > sizeof(tempbuf)) {
        temp = malloc(elemSize);
        assert(temp != NULL);
    }

    char (* const Array)[elemSize] = arr;

    for (int S = 1; S < n; ++S) {
        memcpy(temp, &Array[S], elemSize);
        int I = -1;
        if (Compare(temp, &Array[0]) >= 0) {
            I = S-1;
            while (Compare(temp, &Array[I]) < 0) --I;
        }
        memmove(&Array[I+2], &Array[I+1], (S-I-1)*elemSize);
        memcpy(&Array[I+1], temp, elemSize);
    }

    if (temp != tempbuf)
        free(temp);
}

// Not really the bubble sort
void bubbleSort(void *arr, int n, int elemSize,
                int (*Compare)(const void *, const void *)) {
    insertionSort(arr, n, elemSize, Compare);
}
```

#### Is it sorted?

After you code your sort routine, you can verify if it is sorted with a validator function. Such a function would just scan the array elements and make sure the successive elements are less than or equal to each other.

```
void verifySort(void *arr, int n, int elemSize,
                int (*Compare)(const void *, const void *)) {

    char (* const Array)[elemSize] = arr;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        assert(Compare(&Array[i-1], &Array[i]) <= 0);
    }
}
```